# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Instance Logs with ASP.NET

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an ASP.NET application running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  The website is running correctly but I'm having trouble configuring AWS tail log to get the log4net logfile.

I'm using log4net to output logs to a file as follows.

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\testlog.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %level %thread %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

I've created `.ebextensions\testlog.config` in my project (as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html?icmpid=docs_elasticbeanstalk_console)) and have it copied to the output (I have verified that AWS creates the file in the AWS console event log).

```
files:
  "c:/Program Files/Amazon/ElasticBeanstalk/config/taillogs.d/testlog.conf" :
    content: |
      C:\testlog.log
```

When I try to get the logs (Logs -> Request Logs -> Last 100 lines -> Download), I see this error:

```
Faulting application path: c:\Program   Files\Amazon\ElasticBeanstalk\Tools\TailLogs.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: df345c3f-af75-11e6-8155-06f0078a1fb7
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
2016-11-20T23:05:48.000Z Error 0:(0) .NET Runtime - Application: TailLogs.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentException
   at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(System.String, Boolean, Int32, Boolean)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(System.String, Boolean, Int32, Boolean)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(System.String)
   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Init(System.String, Boolean)
   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo..ctor(System.String)
   at AWSBeanstalkCfnUtility.LogInfo.GetLogFiles(System.String)
   at AWSBeanstalkCfnUtility.FileUtil.scanLogDirectories(System.IO.TextWriter, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<AWSBeanstalkCfnUtility.LogInfo>)
   at AWSBeanstalkCfnTailLogsApp.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

I've tried logging to different file paths (`C:\inetpub\logs\`, `C:\Program Files\Amazon\ElasticBeanstalk\logs\`) but I keep getting the same error.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the issue, I needed to set write permissions to the folder that the log was going into.

```
container_commands:
  01-changeperm:
    command: icacls.exe c:\\inetpub\\logs /grant "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool":(OI)(CI)M > c:\\cfn\\perms.log 2>&1
    waitAfterCompletion: 0

files:
  "c:/Program Files/Amazon/ElasticBeanstalk/config/taillogs.d/applog.conf":
    content: |
      C:\inetpub\logs\app.log
```